# Updating an array based on an index Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I am trying to update an object inside of an array. Here is my structure:

```
"_id": "ubtQP9EjmxhXS5z98",
"name": "My Data",
"desc": "What songs should I play at my wedding?",
"private": false,
"suggestions": [
  {
    "name": "Vote 1",
    "link": "http://www.website.com/",
     "votes": 0
  },
  {
    "name": "Vote 2",
    "votes": 0
  }
],
"author": "tovd9Win3C3fntgyR",
"createdAt": "2016-01-10T08:36:37.014Z"
```

And here is my update code:

```
Meteor.methods({
  voteup: function(itemIndex, userId){
    Polls.update({"_id": "ubtQP9EjmxhXS5z98"}, {
      "$inc": {"suggestions."+itemIndex+".votes": 1}
    });
  }
});
```

This does not work. It just crashes my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to build your query dynamically like this:

```
Meteor.methods({
  voteup: function(itemIndex, userId) {
    var update = {};
    update["suggestions."+itemIndex+".votes"] = 1;
    Polls.update({"_id": "ubtQP9EjmxhXS5z98"}, {
      "$inc": update
    });
  }
});
```